Does inflation really answer why the universe is almost flat?
Inflation does not really adress why our universe is very close to flat - curvature $k$ is a constant in FLRW metric, it has to be very close to zero to begin with. All that inflation solves is it does not require the universe to start with a density very close to critical to achieve that curvature. From the first friedman equation we can deduce that $(\frac{\rho _c}{\rho}-1) \rho a^2 = k \times constant$, here $k$ remains constant, just $\rho$ need not be very close to $\rho_c$ to begin with - the $\rho a^2$ term will reduce the differences at the universe inflates.
In summary, even though fine tuning in terms of density is not needed, the universe still needs to be fine tuned in terms of curvature to begin with. Inflation does not address that problem. Is my reasoning right?

That question was already answered at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/836127/24093 but since the answer below tells the same story in different words maybe you understand now.

You are confused by the standard way FLRW metric is written where in 3d metric you keep $a^2(t)$ as a common factor multiplied on sphere or hyperboloid metric with unit curvature radius. However, in terms of proper distances and proper surfaces this 3d part behaves as a sphere/hyperboloid with radius curvature being equal to $a(t)$. When this scale factor is very large this spacetime becomes observationally the same as the $k=0$ FLRW metric. You can see that by introducing new coordinate $\tilde{r}=a_0 r$ so that $a(t) /a_0$ is not very large.  For large $a_0$ you get approximately $k=0$ metric
The point is that inflation does not make universe flat by changing topology, no one claims that, it makes universe look flat.
